# Making a Shift Key for a keyboard on a Windows Form

Tags: c#, keyboard, vb.net-to-c#

I've recently started to learn both VB.net and C#.

Anyway, I made a Windows Form application in VB.net that has a keyboard.

To change the keys between upper and lower case, there is also a Shift Key, which works by looping through all of the controls on the form, and changing the case of the control's text based on the tabindex.

**The VB.NET code:**

```
Private bShiftEngaged As Boolean

Private Sub btnShift_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShift.Click
    Dim ctrl As Control

    If bShiftEngaged = False Then

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

            If ctrl.TabIndex >= 20 And ctrl.TabIndex <= 45 Then

                ctrl.Text = LCase(ctrl.Text)

            End If

        Next ctrl

    Else

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

            If ctrl.TabIndex >= 20 And ctrl.TabIndex <= 45 Then

                ctrl.Text = UCase(ctrl.Text)

            End If

        Next ctrl

    End If

End Sub
```

I have tried to replicate this in C#. The problem is that all of the controls change case.

**C# Code:**

```
    private void btnShift_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (bShiftEngaged == false)
            {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
                {
                if (ctrl.TabIndex >= 20 && ctrl.TabIndex <= 45) ;
                    {
                   ctrl.Text = ctrl.Text.ToLower();
                    }
                }
             }
        else
            {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
                {
                if (ctrl.TabIndex >= 20 && ctrl.TabIndex <= 45) ;
                    {
                    ctrl.Text = ctrl.Text.ToUpper();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate help in changing the code so only the controls with a tabindex between `20` and `45` are affected.

Comment: You should debug your code and inspect the contents of this.Controls in both cases.

Comment: Maybe, copying an pasting, now your controls have a different `TabIndex` value (which is a bit *unstable* as a property). Maybe, use the `Tag` Property. Or, probably better, group them in a `List<Control>`. Or in a `List<Class>`, with a custom class that references all of your controls, adding some useful property to identify their usage (something like *CanUppercase*) and other useful characteristics: aspect//layout/specific logic etc. I know, you just started, but custom classes are your good friends, the sooner you meet them, the better.

Comment: @Jimi I did copy and paste the controls from my VB.net project, but reset the Tab Order afterwards to match the code. FWIW, I'm using Visual Studio.It does come across as glitchy at times, but then again I don't know if it's the norm or a bug. Should the code I've posted normally work? I really want to know the C# equivalent for my VB.net code more than anything. Regards using tag property, unfortunately I have that reserved for something else.I guess I could group the keyboard buttons in a Panel or something, but like I mentioned, I'm curious why the C# code fails as is.

Comment: The difference is that in C# you are using `&&` and in VB.Net `And`, while the equivalent would be `AndAlso`. It's always the conditional `AND` operator, but *short-curcuited*, meaning that when a condition evaluates to false, the evaluation stops (the other conditions are not evaluated). In this case won't change the result. If `TabIndex < 20`, then it's not useful to evaluate if it's `<= 45`.  If you evaluate it, it doesn't change the result anyway. You need to debug your code and find out what's what.